# Using FFMPEG to convert an MKV with multiple subtitles, audio tracks and chapters to a plain mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, conversion, mkv, x264

I have MKV files which contain multiple subtitle options, multiple audio options, and multiple chapters.

I'm wanting to convert to MP4. The MKV's are x265 with DD 5.1. I just want x264 MP4's with plain stereo, no subs and the default audio.

All I can find is solutions for converting with hardcoded subs or specific audio tracks. I need all of that stripped away, and more importantly, x265 to x264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple questions; I'll try to answer them separately for simplicity.

First of all, converting from mkv to mp4:
The easiest way would be something like this `ffmpeg -i input.mkv output.mp4`
This will cause ffmpeg to infer the format based on the filename and isn't always possible.

If you need to specify the type explicitly, you can add the parameter `-f <format>`.
In your case, something like this:
`ffmpeg -f matroska -i input.mkv -f mp4 output.mp4`

Note: The format before the input (`-i`) corresponds to the input format, while the format after the input corresponds to the output format.

Next, let's look at the codec:

FFmpeg uses a predefined codec by default; you can disable this by specifying the `copy` codec using `-codec copy`.

There are multiple options to specify a codec, depending on the scenario:

- `-codec copy` Use the original codec for all mapped streams
- `-codec libx264` Convert all video streams to h264 (type of stream is deduced by the codec)
- `-vcodec libx264` Convert video streams to h264 (`-acodec` and `-scodec` for audio and subtitles, respectively)
- `-c copy` Short for `-codec copy`
- `-c:v copy` Short for `-vcodec copy`

In your case, something like `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c libx264 output.mp4` should produce the desired result.

Next, audio channels:

FFmpeg already integrates a downmixer; therefore, the standard solution is to use `-ac 2` (Set the number of audio channels to 2).
As Dolby digital is probably not supported within mp4, you should change the audio codec as well:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c aac -ac 2 output.mp4`

A much more detailed answer is provided [here](https://superuser.com/a/1410620/1130613).

Next, chapters:
Removing chapters is relatively easy; adding the following option `-map_chapters -1` will remove the Chapter-TOC from the output.

Last but not least, stream selection:

The simplest way of selecting a stream is by number, but there are multiple other options:

- `-map 0:0` use the first stream from the first input file
- `-map 0:v:0` select the first video stream from the first input file
- `-map -0:s` everything except subtitles from the first input file
- `-map 0:m:language:eng` select by language
- `-map 0:v:0?` use the first video stream of the first input if exists

To conclude this answer, your final command should look something like this:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mkv \
  -map 0:v:0 \
  -map 0:m:language:eng? \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -c:a aac \
  -map_chapters -1 \
  -ac 2 \
  output.mp4
```

Output contains:

- First video stream
- English audio (if exists)
- No chapters
- Only two audio channels
- video codec: h264
- Audio codec: aac
- Output format: mp4

Hope this helps, and I didn't miss any requirements

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. The solution was actually quite simple, just `ffmpeg -i "C:\video.mkv" -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:a copy "C:\video.mp4"`, but I've saved your reply for future use.